# how to redirect to login page in dotnet core, if the user enters login.aspx in the url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am working on the migration of web forms to dotnet core. i have a login page as login.cshtml and this is set as the default page for the application, I need to redirect to the login page when the user enters login.aspx in the login URL. currently, it is showing as page not found, but I need it to redirect to the login page.

Comment: at the same time, you have both applications running? `webForms` and `.NET Core`

Comment: no , only .netcore application is running. i am checking if we have some thing like page alias

Comment: You need to handle it manually by writing middleware for example. take a look at below link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Answer (score 0):

Can't you do this with forms-based authentication? [Form Based Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/aspnet/development/forms-based-authentication)

Comment: It's better to share answers like this as a comment.